# datatable data of selected row with column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i'm trying to get specific column of my datatable refered by name of the selected row but it select either the row or all data of the specific column never the specific column value of selected row :

```
 var columnValue1 = getTable().column('ALEN:name').rows( { selected: true } ).data();
    var columnValue2 = getTable().rows( { selected: true } ).column('ALEN:name').data();
```

OUTPUT:

Columnvalue1 : output the full selected row not only the column 'ALen' of the selected row
Columnvalue2 : output the data of all lines of the column 'Alen' not only the selected row

Comment: add a snippet or a jsfiddle

Comment: This depends on the initialization of the datatable... can you post datatable initialization?

Comment: here is how i declared the columns into my datatable but this is static example cause i work with globale js file that generate datatabes and i  take all data and column from a callback of another function :
`$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $('#example').dataTable( {
  columns: [

{name: "Alen" title : 'Alen',visible: true},

{name: "Brand"title : 'Brand',visible: true},
   
  ]
  

   
   
  
} );
} );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a function that index on the name then determine what is his position in the selected row for exemple i want to return the value of the row selected with name Alen :

```
var columnValue2 = getTable().rows( { selected: true } ).data()[0][tab.getColumnIndex("Alen")];
```

This is my function:

```
this.getColumnIndex = function(ColumnName){
        var index;
        //dataTableOption : function to declare option of datatable like columns-searching 
        for (let i=0;i<this.dataTableOption.columns.length; i++ ){
            
            if ( this.dataTableOption.columns[i].name == ColumnName){
                
                 index =i;
        }
        }
        return index ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As says in a comment, this depends on DataTable initialization (ajax or precharged data) and if you have single or multiple selection...

**MULTIPLE SELECTION EXAMPLE:**

***If you have datatable with ajax you can access field directly:***

```
var rowsData = getTable().rows({ selected: true }).data().filter(x => x.FieldName <= 0).toArray()
```

***If you don't have ajax and you have precharged data:***

```
var rowsData = getTable().rows({ selected: true }).data().filter(x => x[15] <= 0).toArray()
```

And finally you can iterate over rowsData because is an array of objects (rows) with fields.

**SINGLE SELECTION EXAMPLE:**

***If you have datatable with ajax you can access field directly:***

```
var fieldValue = getTable().row({ selected: true }).data().FieldName
```

***If you don't have ajax and you have precharged data:***

```
var fieldValue= getTable().row({ selected: true }).data()[15]
```

Comment: i want to use fieldname into a precharged data instead of the number of column [15] change it with a name linked to the column or the data [name] is that possible in datatables case ? i tried to add name to every `column columns: [  {name: "Alen" title : 'Alen',visible: true}]` is there any possible way to index the data value from that name when i do a single selection?

Comment: I have tried this time ago but the only way I know is using ajax. If you find something please tell me !!!

Comment: try this solution maybe it help you in the futur it worked for me